# Count Divs by Class name with Scrolling from the browser

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to count the number of divs by a class name by scrolling down until the end of the HTML?
I have a page I'd to scrape, but I need to scroll down every time to count the "Hidden" divs, which appears after I'm scrolling down the page.

I have the following `document.getElementsByClassName('Class_Name').length`, but it requires me every time to scroll down on the page.
I want to do that on the browser console. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give us the Page Url. And the class name

Comment: If the data is coming from backend after you reach at the bottom then you have to scroll down to bottom in order to get all the data. Otherwise you can do that without scrolling. You have to find out what is the case here.

Comment: If you can't see them when sending an HTTP request, they're not "hidden", they are dynamically generated using javascript. You'll need to use a screen scraper for that, such as `selinium`

Answer (score 0):

```
let divs = new Set()
setInterval(() => {
  divs.add(...document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName'))
}, 500)
```

Run this code in your url and then scroll in the end you will end up with all the divs in the variable divs and about counting the amount of divs you can do `divs.length`

Comment: I didn't understand; I need to scroll or not? I was able to receive results using your peace of code, but I think it's not retrieved all of the results, the number of result change from time to time.

Comment: Well you have to scroll completely and after you have scrolled completely you run the command. In my head it should work just fine. But if you give the url to the page I might be able to make adjustments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
scrollWithSelect = (className, interval = 50, elems = 0, position = [0, 0]) => {
  if (position[1] >= document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)
    return elems;
  elems += document.getElementsByClassName(className).length;
  position[1] += interval;
  window.scrollTo(...position);
  return scrollWithSelect(className, interval, elems, position);
};
```